# Linear Algebra: Inner Products and Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

To evaluate an Inner Product, do we use the coordinates of the vectors (like we do for Norms) or the vectors themselves (in the absolute sense)?

For example, consider the space of polynomials up to 3rd degree with basis : [1, x, x^2, x^3].

Is the following true? The coordinates of the basis vector "x" in R4 is: [0 1 0 0]'.

If we define the inner product in this space to be an integral, I have seen that in the inner products of the basis vectors (say x and x^2), the basis vectors themselves are used, and not their coordinates.

Thanks

Edit: I think I am getting tripped up because I am normally used to the Dot Product, where the basis is generally the unit vectors, and so the coordinates of the vectors are just the vectors themselves.

Comment: You can use either

Comment: Do both cases yield the same answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an ordered basis $e_1,\dots,e_n$ and $v = a_1e_1 + \dots a_ne_n$ then the associated matrix is $[a_1,\dots,a_n]^\top$ (let's say it's a column vector). So for example $x = 0e_1 + 1e_2 + 0e_3 + 0e_4$ then the associated coordinates vector is $[0,1,0,0]^\top$ as you say.

Next, if you have an inner product and you want to describe that inner product in coordinates, you form the Gram matrix $G = [\langle e_i, e_j \rangle]_{i,j=1}^n$. For example if $\langle v, w \rangle = \int_0^1 vw \;dx$ then we have
$$
\langle x^m, x^n \rangle = \frac{1}{1 + m + n}
$$

So that gives us the Gram matrix
$$G =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \frac12 & \frac13 & \frac14 \\
\frac12 & \frac13 & \frac14 & \frac15 \\
\frac13 & \frac14 & \frac15 & \frac16 \\
\frac14 & \frac15 & \frac16 & \frac17
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The way this works is that if $v, w$ are polynomials, whose coordinate vectors I call $[v]$ and $[w]$ then $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]{\langle v, w \rangle = [v]^\top G [w].} $$

For example:
$$ \langle x, x^2 \rangle = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} G \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \frac13 \\ \frac14 \\ \frac15 \\ \frac16 \end{bmatrix} = \frac14. $$

Recall that multiplying a matrix on the right by $[e_i] = [0,\dots,1,\dots,0]^\top$ gives you the $i$-th column of that matrix and multiplying on the left by $[e_i]^\top = [0,\dots,1,\dots,0]$ gives you the $i$-th row.

Comment: To summarize, are you saying that: if we use the dot (edit: inner) product as defined normally (in this case, the integral), then we use the vectors themselves. If we want to use the coordinates of the vectors, then we form the Gram Matrix, which is the inner product defined in coordinates?

Comment: @ChocoChip Well you wouldn't call it a "dot product" but yes. I'm pretty sure everyone reserves the term "dot product" for the product defined by $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 + \dots + a_nb_n$. You could call it an/the inner product.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write inner product.

Comment: Does the Gram matrix technique hold in general, for different vector spaces and inner products?

Comment: @ChocoChip at least for finite vector spaces, yes. All inner products on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are of the form $v^\top Aw$ for some symmetric, positive definite matrix $A$ (meaning $v^\top Av \ge 0$ for all $v$ and $v^\top A v = 0$ iff $v = 0$). Conversely, given any arbitrary inner product, you can recover the matrix $A$ by computing the Gram matrix.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I have a few more follow up questions, are you willing to answer them here?

Comment: @ChocoChip it would be better to make a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something you should notice:

Let $ V,<,> $ be an inner product space of finite dimensional.  And let  $ B={b_1,b_2,...,b_n} $ be an orthonormal basis for $ V $.

Then for any $ u,v \in V $, i'll sign by $ <,>_{st} $ the dot product, and it follows that

$ <u,v> = <[u]_B,[v]_B>_{st} $

Where $ [u]_B,[v]_B $ indicates the coordinates vectors of $ u $ and $ v $ by the orthobornal basis, respectivly.

Note : this is not necesssarily true if the basis is not orthonormal.

Comment: You are saying that if the basis is orthonormal, then the dot product of two vectors is the same regardless of whether I use the coordinates or the vectors themselves?

Comment: To be more precise: it's true if and only if the basis is orthonormal.

Comment: @ChocoChip Not exactly. What I say is that using any inner product on 2 vectors will get the same result as using the standard inner product (what you called the dot product) on the coordinates vectors by an orthonormal basis.

Comment: Awesome, thank you